# For $ y \neq 0, z \neq 0$, show $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{w}{z} \iff xz = yw$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading a set of online notes by David Joyce on Modern Algebra. I took an undergraduate course in it a while back, trying to get back into it. It hasn't been spelled out yet that we have cancellation laws $($i.e. $ax = bx \implies a = b$ if $x \neq 0)$ and it asks us to show, in a field $F$:

$$\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{w}{z} \iff xz = yw$$

So far I can take the left side and get it into a form that looks like

$$(xz)(yz)^{-1} = (yw)(yz)^{-1}$$

The right side will get me to

$$(xy^{-1})(yz) = (wz^{-1})(yz)$$

Can I assume I have cancellation laws and just be done with this? If not, I am not seeing the way to advance and would appreciate a nudge.

### --

### --

EDIT: Here is what I did from left side so people know where I am

$$\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{w}{z}$$
$$xy^{-1} = wz^{-1}$$
$$xy^{-1}\cdot 1 = wz^{-1} \cdot 1$$
$$xy^{-1}\cdot zz^{-1} = wz^{-1} \cdot yy^{-1}$$
$$xz\cdot y^{-1}z^{-1} = yw\cdot y^{-1}z^{-1}$$
$$(xz)(yz)^{-1} = (yw)(yz)^{-1}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$xz = yw$$

Comment: For one direction of the implication, you multiply by $yz$ and for the other direction, you divide by $yz$. You can because $yz \neq 0$

Comment: @RobinNicole Intuitively, yes. Piece of cake and we're done. But off of the basic field axioms, I cannot do this...

Comment: In some contexts, this is the _definition_ of what it _means_ for two fractions to equal each other, and so not a matter of proof in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  I'd say you have to prove the cancelation laws.  But you can prove them separately.

......

In a field the *definitions* are that if $y\ne 0$ then there does exist $k$ in the field so that $k*y = 1$.  The notation $\frac 1y$ is simply the notation for this $k$.

So in a field $\frac 1y*y = 1$ *by definition*.

And in a field if $x$ and $w$ are elements then $x*w$ is also an element so for $y \ne 0$ and $x$ then we know that $x*\frac 1y$ is an element.  The notation $\frac xy$ is just notation for $x * \frac 1y$.

.....

So cancelation laws:

Lemma 1 (separation law):  $(az)^{-1} = a^{-1}z^{-1}$ or in other notation $\frac 1{az} = \frac 1a \frac 1z$.

Proof:  $(az)(a^{-1}z^{-1}) = (az)(z^{-1}a^{-1}) = a(z*z^{-1})a^{-1} = a*1*a^{-1} = a*a^{-1} = 1$.

So $(az)^{-1} = a^{-1}z^{-1}$.

Or $az\frac 1a \frac 1z = a*\frac 1a * z\frac 1z = 1*1=a$.

Lemma (cancelation law):  $(wz)(az)^{-1} = wa^{-1}$ or in other notation $\frac {wz}{az} = \frac wa$

Proof:

So $(wz)(az)^{-1} = (w*z)*(a^{-1}*z^{-1}) = w*a^{-1}*z*z^{-1} = w*a^{-1}*1 =w*a^{-1}$.

Or in other notation:  $\frac {wz}{az} = wz*\frac 1{az} = wz*\frac 1a\frac 1z = w*\frac 1a*z*\frac 1z =w*\frac 1a = \frac wa$.

.....

But, frankly, I wouldn't use it at all.

I'd do.

$xz = wy \implies$

$xz*\frac 1y = wy*\frac 1y$

$\frac xy*z = w$

$\frac xy*z*\frac 1z = w\frac 1z$

$\frac xy = \frac wz$.

========

Post script:  I'd actually use this result to prove the cancelation law:

$\frac xy = \frac wz \iff xz = wy$

So $\frac {xz}{yz} = \frac xy \iff (xz)y = x(yz)\iff xyz = xyz$.  And that proves the cancelation law.  (Assuming I did not use the cancelation law to prove the result in the first place.)

=====

Post-post script.

You Left hand side seems a bit complicated.

Id simply to $\frac xy = \frac wz \implies

$ x*\frac 1y*y*z = w*\frac 1z*yz =\ w\frac 1z*z*y$

$ x*1*z =  w*1*y$

$xz=wy$.

....

If we use the observation that if $a \ne 0$ then $ax = ay \implies a^{-1}ax = a^{-1}ay \implies  x=y\implies ax = ay$ and therefore $ax=ay\iff x=y$  then we can actually do this if and only steps at the same time.

$\frac xy =\frac wz \iff$

$\frac xy*yz = \frac wz*yz \iff$

$x*\frac 1y*y*z = w*\frac 1z*z *y\iff$

$xz = wy$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $xz = wy$

iff (by multiplication with the inverses of $y$ and $z$) $\frac{xz}{yz} = \frac{wy}{zy}$

iff $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{w}{z}$.

The cancellation law is not needed, since you take $\frac{xz}{yz} = (xz)(z^{-1}y^{-1}) = x(zz^{-1})y^{-1} = xy^{-1}=\frac{x}{y}$.

As a note, cancellation is a big thing in rings. If $a\ne 0$ is not a zero divisor and $ax=ay$, then $x=y$. You don't require that $a$ is invertible.

Comment: I know cancellation was huge when I took the course. My issue is that I was given the field axioms (no cancellation explicitly given) and asked to show this. When I took the course, we went Groups -> Rings -> Fields. This course is going backwards.

Comment: In fields (or groups) it always holds as you can always multiply with the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

If $y,z\in F$ are nonzero then $y^{-1}$ and $z^{-1}$ exist. Then
$$xy^{-1}=wz^{-1}$$
implies that
$$(xy^{-1})(yz)=(wz^{-1})(yz)$$
Because multiplication is associative and commutative, this is equivalent to
$$x(y^{-1}y)z=w(z^{-1}z)y,$$
and by definition of the inverse this is equivalent to
$$xz=wy.$$
To see that the first implication is in fact an equivalence, note that $yz\neq0$ so we can multiply by $(yz)^{-1}$.

---

In general you have cancellation in a field because every nonzero element has an inverse; if $x\neq0$ then
$$ax=bx\quad\Rightarrow\quad (ax)x^{-1}=(bx)x^{-1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad a=b.$$

Comment: But how do I know that I can freely multiply each side by the same thing on the right? I know that I can, but not necessarily in this context. Is it safe to assume?

Comment: That depends on what you are willing to assume, but this is generally assumed to be a fundamental property of equality: If $a=b$ then $ax=bx$.

Comment: Although we can get as abstract and theoretical as we want, for this level it is assumed that when you say "$a = b$" you are saying $a$ and $b$ are the exact same thing.  And it is assumed that if you do something to a value, it is ... doing something to a value.  So if $a$ and $b$ are both different labels for the same person "Sam"  and if you drive $a$ to the opera.  Than thats the same thing as driving $b$ to the opera becaue $a$ and $b$ are just labels for Sam and they both mean "drive Sam to the opera".